# Alarm Software: Compatible with iOS, Android, Mac, PC

Tags: javascript, android, ios

I want to build up an `alarm software` using `Javascript`. It will be a normal **Desktop Application**. Is this software usable in `iPhone`, `Android`, `Mac` also? If YES,then how? Any additional matter needed?

Comment: You guys are being way to critical with this question. It is extremely clear what the OP is asking. The grammar and terminology may not be perfect, but there is more than enough information here to offer an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lutfor the short answer is No.

Firstly a "Desktop Application" is not compatible on an iPhone or Android device these are very different systems.

Second, Java is the correct/native language for Android but does not work for iPhone or Mac (by default).

There are tools you can use to develop an application in one language (say Java) and port that to iPhone (iOS) but this method is pretty limited.

There really isnt a simple answer I can give you to get you in the right direction but I can give you a few questions to ask your self.

1. What "desktops" do you want your application to work on? Windows, Mac, Linux? There are tools where you can write the application in one language and port to all these desktops but again you are limited in function somewhat and performance will be hindered. I suggest writing the application in each operating systems native language(s).
2. What mobile platforms do you want to support? Android, iOS, others? I suggest focusing on Android and iOS. Again you can use tools that will allow you to write in one language and port to both platforms but you are again limited in function.

Given you mentioned Java I assume you may have at least some background with it? I would start there and target making your application for Android devices. Once you master that, look into writing the application for iPhone (iOS).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. I want to build up my application on Windows.

Comment: It should be JavaScript

Comment: @LutforRahman , if you are looking to use JavaScript then you are talking about a web based application and based on the little information I know about your project that probably is not going to be ideal. Start a new question that better explains the what the application is for and invite me to it. I will try and get you going in the right direction.